# Como consigo adicionar um filtro para listar apenas as países acima de x casos?

Tags: r

```
confirmed <- read.csv('time_series_covid_19_confirmed.csv',
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)

covid <- confirmed %>% select(Country.Region, X3.29.20) %>%
  group_by(Country.Region) %>% 
  summarise(sum_X3.29.20 = sum(X3.29.20))
```

Answer (score 1):

Só adicionar um `filter` ao final da função:

```
library(dplyr)

covid <- confirmed %>% select(Country.Region, X3.29.20) %>%
  group_by(Country.Region) %>% 
  summarise(sum_X3.29.20 = sum(X3.29.20)) %>% 
  filter(sum_X3.29.20 > 500)
```

Assim, todos os países com mas de 500 casos de covid-19 serão considerados.